# Unreferenced Assembly error when Entity Framework context implements interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mocking, undefined-reference

I have an Entity Framework context implementing a simple interface. These both live in a Data class library, which is referenced by another Core class library. The Data library has a reference to Entity Framework 6, and all EF specific code lives there. No other parts of the system have any EF references.

I've just introduced this interface to allow me to mock out a database connection and start unit testing both of these libraries, but I'm struggling to replace the concrete class with the new interface. Attempts at doing so are telling me I'm missing an Entity Framework reference in the Core library, which I'd rather avoid having.

**App (Core library)**

```
// Not actual code, but 
public App()
{
    AppContext c = new AppContext(); // No errors, compiles and runs
    IAppContext i = new AppContext(); // Doesn't compile, unreferenced assembly
 }
```

The exact error is CS0012 - The type 'DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework'.

I'm struggling to understand why this error only appears when the variable I'm assigning to is of the interface and not the concrete type. The interface setup is straightforward enough, and it doesn't bring in any EF references.

**Interface and Implementation (Data library)**

```
// IAppContext.cs
public interface IAppContext
{
    DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    // A few more DbSets

    int SaveChanges();
}

// AppContext.Interface.cs
public partial class AppContext : IAppContext
{ }
```

**Intended Mock Usage**

```
// TestContext.cs
public class TestContext : IAppContext
{
    // Mock up DbSets using Moq or equivalent
}
```

Eventually, this library wont be responsible for instantiating the context anyway, it will be passed in as a constructor parameter. I'd still like to know why this particular set up is throwing this error though, it doesn't make any sense to me.

I've created a minimal project with the same behaviour, including only the code listed above, and an empty class replacing the Context, which inherits System.Data.Entity.DbContext, and implements IAppContext. The Data library adds only the EntityFramework Reference. The Core library references only the Data library.

While slightly off-topic, if I'm going in the complete wrong direction here, and there's a better way of mocking this out, I'm all ears! This is the way I've mocked up an EF context in the past, although that was for a small project where everything was in a single assembly.

Comment: Your setup causes no errors on my system. Please provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: I've just created a new project, as described in the question, and I'm getting the same error. Data library with the context and interface, Core library with a single class with both instantiations in the question. I'll update the question and add exactly which references I added to it, in case it's something else that's causing this.